# I would like to search for list of stings in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a column in my CSV file in which I would like to search for list of strings and add a new column of 0/1, if any value from the list is present then 1 else 0.

I have two lists :

1. 'UC''iCD', 'Chrons disease', 'Chrons', 'IBD', 'Ulcerative 
   colitis', 'PMC', 'P80', 'Chron disease'
2. Donor, healthy, non-IBD, Control.

My column also has NA values

By far I have this in which I was just trying to match list of stings:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

with open('biosample.csv') as csvfile:
    df = pd.read_csv('biosample.csv', delimiter = ',', dtype= 'unicode', 
    error_bad_lines=False)
    df1 = df.set_index(['Sample_Info'])
print(df1.loc['UC''iCD', 'Chrons disease', 'Chrons', 'IBD', 'Ulcerative 
colitis', 'PMC', 'P80', 'Chron disease])
```

To this I am getting multiple errors like in _has_valid_type_error,in has_valid_type_error.

I have gone through already posted questions but in none this kind of errors are mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [84]: df
Out[84]:
   a   b    c    new
0  1  11  aaa   True
1  2  22  bbb  False
2  3  33  ccc   True
3  4  44  ddd  False

In [85]: lst = ['aaa','ccc','xxx']

In [86]: df['new'] = df['c'].isin(lst).astype(np.int8)

In [87]: df
Out[87]:
   a   b    c  new
0  1  11  aaa    1
1  2  22  bbb    0
2  3  33  ccc    1
3  4  44  ddd    0
```

PS you don't need to use CSV module at all:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'/path/to/biosample.csv', delimiter = ',', 
                 encoding='unicode', error_bad_lines=False, 
                 index_col='Sample_Info')
```

Comment: Hi MaxU this is not helping me because my the column in my csv sheet has values like this :                                                                                                      HC,HC
UC,UC
CC,CC
UC,UC
UC,UC
LC,LC
CD,ICD_r
no IBS,No,no IBD
Donor
no IBS,Yes,Ulcerative colitis
no IBS,Yes,Ulcerative colitis
no IBS,No,no IBD
NA
remission,Crohn Disease,pathological
NA
remission,Ulcerative Colitis,pathological
NA
remission,Ulcerative Colitis,pathological

Comment: @K.S, can you post a small reproducible data set and your desired data set. Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Comment: My column contains multiple string seperated by comma. The df is taking only the first value. For example the cell JN1 has value "UC,UC", JN2 - "remission,No IBS, No IBD"  JN3 - "Healthy,normal', JN4 - "Chrons Disease, IBD". I had these values in multiple column which I combined in one column using this:                                                     
    new = df1.apply(lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)                              Now I want new column which has corresponding value of 0 for Chrons disease as 0 and healthy as 1.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use csv module while loading dataframe from csv file.

As you mentioned new column should be added to dataframe.

The code for checking values to be from the first list may be like this:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = ['UC''iCD', 'Chrons disease', 'Chrons', 'IBD', 'Ulcerative colitis', 'PMC', 'P80', 'Chron disease']
list2 = ['Donor', 'healthy', 'non-IBD', 'Control']

def check_list(value, list2check):
    if any(map(lambda x: x in value, list2check))
        return 1
    return 0

df = pd.read_csv('biosample.csv', delimiter = ',', dtype= 'unicode', error_bad_lines=False)
df['sample_from_list1'] = df['Sample_Info'].apply(lambda v: check_list(v, list1))
```

Comment: Hi MaxU this is not helping me because my the column in my csv sheet has values like this :                                                                                                 Sample_Info                                                                                                     
HC,HC
UC,UC
CC,CC
UC,UC
UC,UC
LC,LC
CD,ICD_r
no IBS,No,no IBD
Donor
no IBS,Yes,Ulcerative colitis
no IBS,Yes,Ulcerative colitis
no IBS,No,no IBD
NA
remission,Crohn Disease,pathological
NA
remission,Ulcerative Colitis,pathological
NA
remission,Ulcerative Colitis,pathological